# In MongoDB, how do I safely remove documents which contain an empty array?

Tags: mongodb

If the property in question is "urls", my intuition tells me the following would work:

`db.collection_123.remove({ "urls": [] });`

I would just rather not test it out, if it had some unexpected behavior, like deleting every document whose `urls` value was an array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To safely remove documents which contain an empty array, use a combination of the [**`$exists`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) (which matches the documents that contain the `url` field if the operator is set to true, including documents where the field value is null) and [**`$size`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) operators:

```
db.collection_123.remove({ url: { $exists: true, $size: 0 } });
```

Comment: Good spot. Since MongoDB is schemaless, there may well be documents otherwise needed which do not have the `urls` field at all. In this case, `urls.0` would evaluate to `null`, too – which might lead to unwanted deletions.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I concur, there's need to check for documents with url field having null values as well.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said good spot. The documents not having the `urls` array may be an accidental deletion.

Comment: I get `Property 'remove' does not exist on type 'Collection<Document>'.`. I do not understand why. Line is `db(dbWeb).collection(coll).remove({ $size: 0 })`. I want to delete empty documents shown as `{}`

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you can always check what would be deleted by using an according `find`, which takes the same query.

Now to your problem. Basically, you are looking for each document which does not have at least one entry in the array. The first entry in an array is denoted by it's index, namely 0. So the first entry of the `urls` array of a document would be `urls.0`. And you want all documents which do not have this.

So first, you can check your query by issuing:

```js
db.collection.find({ "urls.0": {$exists:false} })
```

If you find that the results are actually as expected, you can delete the documents with

```js
db.collection.remove({ "urls.0": {$exists:false} })
```

See the [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) for further details.

Comment: Thanks, I should've realized find would be a suitable test! Doh!

Comment: @BryceJohnson  Please see the answer of chridam. He has more than a valid point.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
db.collection_123.remove({ "urls.0": {$exists: false} });
```

This basically checks whether a value exists at index 0 hence determining whether the array is empty or not.

Comment: That looks good, thanks --I'm new to mongodb -- could you point me in the direction of a doc about that dot notation you're using?